# Disable automatic disconnect from the Internet when inactive

Tags: networking, wireless, settings

Ubuntu community, I have a really silly and simple question for you.

I'm completely new to Ubuntu and just installed version 16.04.1 LTS yesterday.

I happened to click the option to disconnect automatically from the network when inactive (or maybe I just left it on, either way it's ticked). Every time I close my laptop it seems to disconnect from the Internet. Now that I regret doing this, I cannot find that option again anywhere in Settings. I'd like to be told where to find that or what commands to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten no responses here, but somebody elsewhere made a good suggestion: to simply go to System Settings, then Power, then in the "When the lid is closed" select the "Do nothing" option. This way my laptop won't disconnect when closing the lid.

Simple and silly answer for a simple and silly question, I s'ppose.